# Multipart column names in update statement with select

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm sure this could be a duplicate but I can't seem to find the right search phrase.

Given a table in a named schema (i.e. not dbo) requires you include the schema name in the statement.  So previously I'd have simply written it as so:

```
UPDATE [Schema].[Table1]
SET [AColumn] = 
( 
    SELECT [SomeColumn] 
    FROM [Schema].[Table2] 
    WHERE [Schema].[Table2].[SameColumnName] = [Schema].[Table1].[SameColumnName] 
);
```

But since [`More than two-part column name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver15) is deprecated, I need to find a new way to do this which is future proof.  I have come up with 2 options, firstly using an alias:

```
UPDATE [Alias1]
SET [AColumn] = 
( 
    SELECT [SomeColumn] 
    FROM [Schema].[Table2] [Alias2] 
    WHERE [Alias2].[SameColumnName] = [Alias1].[SameColumnName] 
)
FROM [Schema].[Table1] [Alias1];
```

The second way is the one I'm really having trouble finding out if it's truly *VALID* `T-Sql`:

```
UPDATE [Schema].[Table1]
SET [AColumn] = 
( 
    SELECT [SomeColumn] 
    FROM [Schema].[Table2] 
    WHERE [Table2].[SameColumnName] = [Table1].[SameColumnName] 
);
```

I have tested both and they work, so my question is, is the second completely valid and normal to use just the table name without the `Schema` in this sense or should I rather opt for the slightly more verbose `Alias`?

Comment: Alias your objects and prefix the column name with the alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, alias your objects.

```
SELECT MT.MyColumn,
       YT.MyColumn
FROM dbo.MyTable MT
     JOIN so.YourTable YT ON MT.ID = YT.fID
WHERE YT.[name] = N'Jane';
```

If you're performing an `UPDATE`, then specify the alias of the object to Update:

```
UPDATE MT
SET MyColumn = YT.MyColumn --Column on the left side of the SET will always reference the table being updated
FROM dbo.MyTable MT
     JOIN so.YourTable YT ON MT.ID = YT.fID
WHERE YT.[name] = N'Jane';
```

Comment: Cool, thanks, appreciate the prompt response, however, is the second way valid?  I am intrigued by it and want to understand if it's valid or just bad code.

Comment: Yes, it's valid, @Storm . I wouldn't have posted it if it wasn't.